# Pass parameters to Presenters (fuelphp)

Tags: fuelphp

How does one pass a parameters to a Presenter? Reading the documentation there doesn't seem to be a way.

https://fuelphp.com/docs/general/presenters.html

Controller

```
    $points = Presenter::forge('points', 'viewmy');
    $points->set('id', 5);
```

Presenter class or view (I tried both):

```
var_dump($id);
var_dump($this->id);
```

Both var_dumps generate an undeclared variable error

This in the Presenter class also did not work:
    $id = $this->get('id');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got to the bottom of this issue. I was using the setview function in my Presenter to change based on condition. This was meaning that any values that I had set were getting lost.

Passing the view into the 4th parameter of forge and not setting it in the presenter fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the page you linked:

> In your code, Views and Presenters are interchangeable. You can return Presenters from your controller actions, you can set a Presenter as a Theme partial, or assign it to a section of your page template. The basic API of the Presenter is compatible with the View. This makes it easy to swap a View for a Presenter in your code without having to do a major code overhaul.

They have the exact same interface as regular View objects.

So as per https://fuelphp.com/docs/general/views.html you can do things like using the `set()` method or passing the parameters in the `forge()` method.