# Is it possible to pass value from controller to presenter in Fuelphp?

Tags: fuelphp, presenter

I have controller and presenter and I want to pass directly pass value from controller to presenter, not in the view.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: After reading the [docs](https://fuelphp.com/docs/general/presenters.html) and trying to do the job, what does your code look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass parameters to Presenters (fuelphp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964019/pass-parameters-to-presenters-fuelphp)